# Errno 0 when reading/writing to a file

Tags: python

This is some example data from the csv I'm reading/writing to:

```
ALTIMA_SD,2014,12,Promoter,Promoter,3/5/2015
ALTIMA_SD,2015,3,Promoter,Promoter,3/5/2015
PATHFINDER,2014,12,Promoter,Promoter,3/5/2015
```

I'm looking to add a column between the first two, so that the end product looks like this:

```
ALTIMA_SD,Comparo,2014,12,Promoter,Promoter,3/5/2015
SENTRA,Comparo,2015,3,Promoter,Promoter,3/5/2015
PATHFINDER,Pathfinder,2014,12,Promoter,Promoter,3/5/2015
```

This is my code:

```
with open('pathfinder query2.csv','r+') as myfile:
for i in myfile:
    i=i.rstrip('\n')
    i=i.split(',')
    if i[0]=='PATHFINDER' or i[0]=='PATHFINDER_H':
        myfile.write(str(i[0])+','+'Pathfinder'+','+str(i[1])+','+str(i[2])+','+str(i[3])+','+str(i[4])+','+str(i[5])+'\n')
    else:
        myfile.write(str(i[0])+','+'Comparo'+','+str(i[1])+','+str(i[2])+','+str(i[3])+','+str(i[4])+','+str(i[5])+'\n')
```

I'm getting a `IOError: [Errno 0] Error` in reference to line 8. I've seen in other posts that the `myfile.seek()` function should be used, but I'm not sure how to apply it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Trying to read from and write to a single file is an invitation to confusion, even not error.  You're growing the file (it is larger as a result of your operations), which definitely worries me.

Comment: It looks like you just never came up with a sane algorithm to perform the modification you want to make.

Answer (score 1):

Opening a file in Python is similar to fopen in C, see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) for an overview of the modes. The problem is you are opening the file with `r+` (read + update), while you need to open your file with `w+` (write + update). Hence you must change your code to:

```
with open('pathfinder query2.csv','w+') as myfile:
```

Also as commented (Thx. Jon.), it's not wise to read and write to the same file. I would recommend you make a copy of the file or read the entire file to a buffer.